# Why are my controllers methods not available?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, angularjs-controller, angularjs-controlleras

after a long time I have to concentrate an angular again. 
But I fail...

... ng-repeat="n in DataController.getObjects"

```
myApp.controller('DataController', [function () {

    console.log('test 1');

    var getObjects = function () {
        console.log('test 2');
        return [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
    };

}]);
```

It is writing test 1 to console but not test 2. And the frontend does not get the array.

Any hint for me?

Regards 
n00n

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to expose `method`/`variable` which you want to access on page on `this`(context) of your controller. So that you can access that method/variable via controller alias as you you seems to be using `controllerAs` pattern.

**Code**

```
myApp.controller('DataController', [function () {
    var self = this;
    console.log('test 1');
    var getObjects = function () {
        console.log('test 2');
        return [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
    };

    self.getObjects = getObjects;
}]);
```

I hope you have already defined controller alias while using `ng-controller` directive, If you haven't used it, follow below.

```
ng-controller="DataController as dataCtrl"

ng-repeat="n in dataCtrl.getObjects()"
```

And as you can see you should call method in `ng-repeat` like `getObjects()` to get a array from method.

Comment: Still not working

.controller('DataController', [function () {

    var self = this;

    console.log('test 1');

    var getObjects = function () {
        console.log('test 2');
        return [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
    };

    self.getObjects = getObjects;

}]);

and yes I did: 
<div lng-controller="DataController as ctrl">
        <div class="pin" ng-repeat="n in ctrl.getObjects"

Comment: check updated answer, Thanks ;) YOu missed to call `getObjects` method